# Baconjs return only last debounce value

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, frp, bacon.js

Here is the code sample:

```
let watcher;
const streamWatcher = bacon.fromBinder(sink => {
    watcher = chokidar.watch(root, {
        ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../
    });
    watcher.on('all', (event, path) => {
        sink({
            event: event,
            path: path
        });
        return () => {
            watcher.unwatch(root);
        };
    });
});
streamWatcher
    .skipDuplicates(_.isEqual)
    .map('.path')
    .scan([], (a, b) => {
        a.push(b);
        return a;
    })
    .debounce(300)
    .onValue(files => {
        if (files.length) {
            console.log('change event fired');
            tinyLrSrv.changed({
                body: {
                    files: files
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

What I am trying to do is to use chokidar watch a folder change (a web dir under development) then using `Bacon.js` to wrap and debounce (because I don't want to know each file change, just tell me in a batch) and return the array of files that changed.

The problem is - the array is from the beginning, so everytime file change, it just keeps adding to the original array.

What I want to get is the last changed array of files, in another word, every time the `onValue` receives the array, the variable that holds the array needs to reset.

Is there a pure bacon.js way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of a super "pure" way to do this nicely. Did you notice that you're actually mutating your buffer in `scan`? You could exploit this and actually clear the buffer in your `onValue` code. Just remember to clone the buffer when sending to tinyLrSrv. Another way would be to use a variable:

```
var files = []
streamWatcher.skipDuplicates(_.isEqual).map('.path')
  .doAction(a => files.push(a))
  .debounce(300)
  .onValue(() => {
    if (files.length) {
      timyLrSrv.changed({body: {files}})
      files = []
    }
  })
```

I've had a similar problem myself and haven't figured out a nice "pure" way to do this. Please submit an Issue against Bacon.js and we can figure out if there's something we should add to Bacon.js core.

Comment: I did try this, but the subsequence data return empty. I mean using the `scan` but I haven't tried the doAction. Will give it a try.

Comment: The doAction works. The scan doesn't (even reset the array after the onValue), this is an interesting behavior of Bacon.js

Comment: If you want to discuss why a certain approach (somthing based on scan?) doesn't work even if you think it should, you can post an Issue against the bacon.js github codebase and we'll have a look. Please include runnable code.

Comment: cool thanks, I am actually building a little game with Bacon.js at the moment. So definitely I will have quite a few things want to say :)